# html5 textarea cannot be stretch in smart devices

Tags: php, android, html, html5boilerplate

I'm using an html textarea in one of my html pages. I'm using html5 **boilerplate** template. The pages can be viewed with out any problem in any device. But the textarea element cannot be stretched. The even the pattern at bottom right-hand corner in every textarea (which indicates that it can be stretched further) is not visible as well.

For further clarifications here's how the page looks like in PC (Chrome) and iPhone (safari).
[image: Output from Chrome browser] 
*Output from Chrome browser*
[image: image from Iphone] 
*Output from Iphone Safari*

You can see the textarea is showing differently on two devices. Also this shows the same behaviour in android devices as well.

Here is my code

```
echo("  <form method=\"post\" action=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\">
<text>Content name: </text><input type=\"text\" name=\"content_name\"/>
<text>Content type: </text><input type=\"text\" name=\"content_type\"/>
<text>Content value: </text><textarea cols=\"60\" name=\"content_value\" name=\"content_value\"></textarea>
<text></text><input class=\"submitbtn\" type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\" name=\"submit\"></input>
</form></div>");
```

Please tell me if I'm doing anything wrong. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: that is browser specific.  Chrome will make all textareas stretchable, but most browsers do not do that.

Comment: thanks nycynik. I believe this is what's happening. Could you plz suggest me any element that I can use apart from textarea, which gives the same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove cole="\60\" and set it using css like style="width: 100%;"

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried this. But it didn't worked. Only textarea width increases. But static width on smart phones.

Answer (score 0):

In order to stop chrome from showing the resize, you can add this to your style of the textarea element:

style = "resize: none;"

so you get

```
<textarea style=\"resize: none;\" cols=\"60\" name=\"content_value\" name=\"content_value\">
```